# What may be causing my website logo on the nav bar to shift?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to figure this issue out.

On a website I created located here: [website](http://cse134-135-2014.github.io/cse134_group10/index.html)

I have 4 top navigation bar options:

1. Home
2. About
3. Members
4. Contact

Every time you select Home from any other menu option, the CSI logo shifts a bit to the right, and returns back to original position.

Anytime the starting point is from Home, and you go to About or Contact, the logo shifts again, but not if you go to Members. However, if you go from Members to Home, the logo shifts again.

This logo shifting does not occur if you navigate to any other options besides Home.

In Home, which links to my index.html, I have some slider images via javascript, and the only way I know how to temporarily fix this logo shifting is using an inline styling (could be external or internal) and shift the slider images down from the top 351px. Anything less than that will cause an issue.

```
<section class="slider" style="margin-top: 351px;">
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Thanks!

Comment: I just checked, its your CSS

Comment: You might not want to use position absolute for your header

Comment: why was I voted down?...I don't understand...Was it because I was asking for people to look at my website?...I would have posted more code, but I don't know why the issue may lie and I dont want to post the whole thing :(

Comment: @user1631224 You should try to port your problem as a minimal example to a JSFiddle for example. And also avoid using link shorteners, because it masks the original URL. We try to discourage users from posting external links because they suffer from decay which may make your question irrelevant to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the vertical scroll of browser) You have a lot of content to other pages and this causes the vertical scroll, and the vertical scroll has a width 13px (Google chrome), so the title is moved :)

Comment: So there's really nothing I can do to fix it, because it is caused by the browser's scroll due to my contents on the nav bar?

Comment: I think, yes, you cant fix it. But can someone suggest a solution, I am also happy to look at it.

Comment: I wish someone could help :(